# Table View crash on ios 7 on swipe left

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

my app crash whenever i swipe left on a cell, and this what i get

```
-[UITableViewCellScrollView _tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166a1960
-[UITableViewCellScrollView _tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166a1960
Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x2fc08f23 <redacted> + 154
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a39fce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x2fc0c837 <redacted> + 202
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x2fc0b137 <redacted> + 706
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x2fb5a098 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
    5   UIKit                               0x3262ef91 <redacted> + 184
    6   UIKit                               0x325be3f5 <redacted> + 816
    7   UIKit                               0x32468a21 <redacted> + 148
    8   UIKit                               0x325ce0cf <redacted> + 78
    9   UIKit                               0x324681eb <redacted> + 458
    10  UIKit                               0x32467c4b <redacted> + 666
    11  UIKit                               0x3243ce75 <redacted> + 196
    12  UIKit                               0x3243b541 <redacted> + 7120
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x2fbd3fef <redacted> + 14
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x2fbd34b7 <redacted> + 206
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x2fbd1ca7 <redacted> + 630
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x2fb3c769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x2fb3c54b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x34aa96d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
    19  UIKit                               0x3249b891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
    20  Event Receiver                      0x000c3849 main + 116
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a89dab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

i tried to add a Symbolic Breakpoint for -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] but that didnt show which piece of code sent that selector

**update**:  this time i used the simulator, and tried to crash the app and i got this now:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView _tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e46570'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ad91e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018588e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b76243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01ac950b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01ac90ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x00785f7a -[UITableViewCellScrollView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] + 203
    6   UIKit                               0x008b5466 -[UIGestureRecognizer _shouldBegin] + 1309
    7   UIKit                               0x008b1d89 -[UIGestureRecognizer setState:] + 171
    8   UIKit                               0x008e39d7 -[UIPanGestureRecognizer touchesMoved:withEvent:] + 142
    9   UIKit                               0x0099792a -[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer touchesMoved:withEvent:] + 89
    10  UIKit                               0x005597d8 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 649
    11  UIKit                               0x0055a971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    12  UIKit                               0x0052c5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    13  UIKit                               0x00516353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01a6277f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01a6210b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7f1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7e9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7e7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x03dba5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03dba42b GSEventRun + 104
    21  UIKit                               0x00518f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    22  Event Receiver                      0x000056cd main + 141
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x026a5701 start + 1
)
```

Comment: This is just a guess since I would need to see more, but does this only fail on ios7 and does it only fail some of the time?   There is a new left swipe gesture that will "pop" the current view controller. However the guesture has to start near the left edge.  I believe it should be smart enough to not pop the "root" view controller, but you may need to flag it that way.

Comment: @dboals i built this project a year ago and it used to work fine, but i started to work on this project again and i noticed this issue when i test it on my 7.1 iphone, i didn't implement any gesture recognition code

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to implement it, you get it for free.  I learned this the hard way.  I didn't crash, but it kept popping my view controller every time I tried to scroll the to the left on my horizontal scrolling window.

Comment: I used this in viewdidload to override the new behavior <pre>    // turn of the annoying new iOS7 left edge gesture.
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doNothing1:)];

        screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
        [topLevelView addGestureRecognizer:screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer];
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    }</pre>

Comment: @dboals thanks, i tried that but i still get the same crash. i am still looking into it

Comment: What does your `doNothing1:` method template structure look like?

Comment: Are you adding views to the cell directly, instead of using the cell’s `contentView` property? I’ve had problems with that breaking things in iOS 7, since they changed the underlying implementation of `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

by applying some coloring to the cell, i saw that when i swipe the cell from the accessory view app crashes

[image]

[image]

---

a work around is to set the accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

[image]

---

**Refs:**
-How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions – Without Going Nuts With Scroll Views [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

-A Closer Look at Table View Cells [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hey ~ I've just solved this bug by removing the codes below in my custom UItableview Cell, but I don't know if it may help you

```
self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

In my case, disable the `userinteractionEnabled` for cell content view will cause exactly the same crash when I trying to swipe left or right in a custom `UItableView` in iOS7,
and it shall be fixed by removing it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify whether you removed or added that line of code? I don't see it present in the asker's question.

Comment: The asker's question hasn't present any of his code, just showing the error log report. That's why I cannot make sure if the reason causing the crash is that line of code I've removed

Comment: Fair enough, Wilson. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error you're getting and these lines:

```
0x01ac90ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
0x00785f7a -[UITableViewCellScrollView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] + 203
```

it appears that you've somehow set an instance of `UITableViewCellScrollView` as the delegate of a gesture recognizer. Since `UITableViewCellScrollView` probably doesn't implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol, you eventually get an unrecognized selector exception.

Examine the gesture recognizer in each of your table cells closely and check the identity of their delegates.

Comment: how would I do that?, infact i have came across UITableViewCellScrollView when i got this crash, i am not implementing any gesture recognition